# Is there any way to create a c# object from the client side in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create a dictionary of addresses from the client side so that the client can store as many addresses as needed before submitting the form and creating the account.

```
@model Cliente
@{
    
    Dictionary<String,Direccion> direcciones = new Dictionary<String,Direccion>();
}
<html lang="es">
<head>
 
</head>
<body>
    <script>
       $('#botonAceptarDirec').click(
           function () {
               console.log('estamos en evento click boton aceptar direccion...');
               var _tipoVia = $('#inputTipoVia').val();
               var _nombreVia = $('#inputNombreVia').val();
               var _numeroVia = $('#inputNumVia').val();
               var _piso = $('#inputPiso').val();
               var _puerta = $('#inputPuerta').val();
               var _bloque = $('#inputBloque').val();
               var _escalera = $('#inputEscalera').val();
               var _urbanizacion = $('#inputUrbanizacion').val();
               var _observaciones = $('#inputObservaciones').val();
               var _codPro = $('#inputProvincia').val();
               var _codMun = $('#inputLocalidad').val();
               var _cp = $('#inputCP').val();
               var _esPrincipal = $('#inputEsPrincipal').val();
               var _iDdireccion = new Guid().ToString();
               
               @direcciones.Add(_iDdireccion, new Direccion(_tipoVia, _nombreVia, _numeroVia, _piso, _puerta, _bloque, _escalera, _urbanizacion, _observaciones, _codPro, _codMun, _cp, _esPrincipal));
               console.log(@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(direcciones))}
       );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to create the address dictionary from the client side using jQuery, but I'm unable to add the object to the dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you use a JavaScript dictionary?

Comment: Hi @Vitalie, could you pls share your scenario? What is this dictionary variable used to do?